# Реализация команд ботов в отдельных классах

Tags: php, бот

Есть, например, 100 файлов, реализующих классы с разными названиями (ну, например, StartCommand, TestCommand, DeleteUsersCommand, ..). В каждом из этих классов есть общее поле - title, в котором записан некоторый текст (применительно к вышеуказанным классам: 'start', 'test', 'delete_users').

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу, имея, например, лишь 'delete_users', понять, в каком из этих классов поле title принимает значение 'delete_users'? Рассматривал идею получить список имен файлов, удовлетворяющих маске '*Command.php'. Поскольку имена файлов эквивалентны названиям классов, то на основе имен файлов я мог бы определять название класса, а значит и создавать объекты этих классов. Ну, а далее через объекты получать значение поля title и сверять с искомым.

Но возникает вопрос: а есть ли это разумно (ибо это создание как максимум 100 объектов разных классов с одной лишь целью - получением значения поля)? Возможно, есть более адекватные решения? Спасибо большое заранее.

Comment: у вас `delete_users` может быть в разных файлах помимо `DeleteUsersCommand.php` ?

Comment: копайте в сторону https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

Comment: @teran, нет, это исключено. Содержимое поля title не может повторяться в других классах - забыл уточнить. Спасибо.

Comment: тогда в чем вопрос вообще? как транслировать `delete_users` в `DeleteUsersCommand` ? Зачем создавать все классы, если вы и так знаете где конкретно находится нужный

Comment: @teran, ну, сама строка delete_users берется извне. Или Вы имеете в виду реализацию алгоритма конвертирования delete_users в DeleteUsers? Кстати, вполне логично. Почему-то не подумал сразу об этом. Спасибо Вам.

Comment: @ArchDemon, кажется, это то, что я и пытаюсь реализовать. Откровенно говоря, ранее я это видел воплощенным лишь на GitHub у одного из проектов Telegram. Но подстроить под себя и разобраться в некоторых моментах так и не смог - решил делать свое. Спасибо!

Comment: Чтобы превратить `delete_users` в `DeleteUsers` достаточно поставить `doctrine/inflector`

Comment: @u_mulder чтобы превратить `delete_users` в `DeleteUsers` в принципе одной строки кода достаточно, смысл таскать зависимости?